# How to add additional classes to django form field

Tags: css, django, forms, django-templates

I've just recently learned about:

```
Form.error_css_class
Form.required_css_class
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.error_css_class

So by defining 'error_css_class' and 'required_css_class' in forms

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'

    name = forms.CharField(...)
```

I can do:

```
<div class="field-wrapper {{ form.name.css_classes }}">
...
</div>
```

This will output:

```
<div class="field-wrapper required">
...
</div>
```

However I want to add additional classes to the field, e.g I would like to add 'text name' css class for the "name" field. And reading the docs, I think its possible.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.css_classes

After reading the above I tried to do

```
self.fields['name'].css_classes('name text')
```

That doesn't work. I get

```
'CharField' object has no attribute 'css_classes'
```

I also tried

```
name = forms.CharField(css_classes='name text')
```

TypeError

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'css_classes'
```

I know I can add extra attr to field widget

```
self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'name text'
```

But I want to add css classes to field wrapper.

I could write a custom templatetag... to check field name/type and return appropriate css classes... but if there is something builtin .. I would love to keep my templates clean :-).

Also hardcoding css classes per field is not an option .. as the form fields are dynamic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using a custom BoundField

```
from django.forms import forms

class CustomBoundField(forms.BoundField):

    def css_classes(self, extra_classes=None):
        # logic for determining css_classes has been omitted 
        extra_classes = ['name', 'text']
        return super(CustomBoundField, self).css_classes(extra_classes=extra_classes)
```

In my forms, I overide **getitem**

```
def __getitem__(self, name):
    try:
        field = self.fields[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError('Key %r not found in Form' % name)
    return CustomBoundField(self, field, name)
```

Comment: Great, and to avoid hard coding adding a property to CustomBoundField class: and call self.extra_classes in css_classes